# Finding a basis of a subspace which is perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let $V = \text{span}\{(1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0, 2, 1), (1, 3, 3, 3, 1)\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$.

I found using Gram-Schmidt process that the orthonormal basis of $V$ is $\{(0.5 , 0.5 , 0 , 0.5 , 0.5), (-0.5 , 0.5 , 0 , 0.5 , -0.5), (0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0)\}$.

Now I am tasked to find a basis of the subspace $V^\perp = \{w ∈ \mathbb R^5\mid w \text{ is orthogonal to }V \}$.

May I ask whether the answer is linked to my orthonormal basis and if it is, what steps do I need to take to obtain the answer?

Thank you.

Comment: $V + V^\perp = \mathbf{R}^5$ and $V \cap V^\perp = \{0\};$ so just complete your basis to one for $\mathbf{R}^5$ and you are done.

Comment: As an alternative method, if you let $A$ be $3x5$ matrix whose rows are your original three vectors, then what you want is (a basis for) the solution space of the system $Ax=0$, which you can find by simple row reduction.